# Looking for ways to make devs aware of shared components

Tags: documentation-generator

We are currently growing in size, and i keep finding devops trying to reinvent stuff that already exist. Is there any tool you guys use that help maling the shared levels a bit more transparent?

Comment: What kind of shared components are we talking about here. Servers, tools, source code?

Comment: Code, actually modules